# error ejb : "No EJB receiver available for handling"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:, distinctName:Biblioo] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@42aee012
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addLivre(Unknown Source)
    at clientlourd.fenetre$2.actionPerformed(fenetre.java:128)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

can't find a solution :\ any help ?!

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JNDI No EJB receiver available for handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293301/jndi-no-ejb-receiver-available-for-handling)

Comment: There's well over a dozen answers to this question already on SO. Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: thanks for all of you, the problem was in the jndi

Answer (score -1):

thank you so much! here is my code :

Context ctx = null;

```
    try{
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        ctx = new InitialContext(p);
        final interface_remote stub =(interface_remote) ctx.lookup("ejb://Biblioo//biblio!bib.interface_remote");
```

JButton button = new JButton("Ajouter");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                stub.addLivre(new Livre());

            }           
    });
```

catch (Exception e)

```
    {

        e.toString();

    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

endpoint.name=client-endpoint

remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=127.0.0.1

remote.connection.default.port = 8080

remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.default.username=admin

remote.connection.default.password=

---

@Remote

public interface interface_remote 
{

```
public void addLivre(Livre L);
public List<Livre> consulterLivres();
public Livre consulterlivres(Long ID_livre);
public void updateLivre(Livre L);
public void supprimerLivre(Long ID_livre);
```

}

---

@Stateless (name="biblio")

public class biblio_Impl implements interface_remote, interface_local
{

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="Biblio")
private EntityManager em;
```

@Override

```
    public void addLivre(Livre L)

    {

        em.persist(L);

    }
```

}